# Use one @StateObject between all view or one per tab-parent view when passing a common view model object - MVVM App

Tags: ios, mvvm, swiftui

In the following example, I have an app with two Tab Views, `Parent View 1` and `Parent View 2`, and each parent view has child views. All of the views share a view model (`cDViewModel`) that handles all of the `Core Data` related stuff. I have read that when passing data around views you should instantiate your object with `@StateObject` and then pass it around to other child views using `@ObservedObject`, clear enough. My confusion is that in my case almost all views in the app will be using the `cDViewModel`. In my app, I'm currently using `Option 1` but I for some reason would like to adopt `Option 2` if possible.

Does it make a difference which of the two methods below you use when sharing a common object within an MVVM app?

---

## Option 1

---

This is how I'm currently using it in my app. Please note that I'm declaring the @StateObject inside the TabView section and start sharing it from there, in other words in this scenario only one instance of the cDViewModel is created.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var cDViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    @State var selectedView = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedView){
            ParentView1(cDViewModel: cDViewModel)
            .tabItem {
                Text("Parent View 1")
            }.tag(0)

            ParentView2(cDViewModel: cDViewModel)
            .tabItem {
                Text("Parent View 2")
            }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

### First Tab View

```
struct ParentView1: View {
    @ObservedObject var cDViewModel:CoreDataViewModel
    NavigationLink(destination: ChildView1(cDViewModel: cDViewModel)){ }
}
struct ChildView1: View {
    @ObservedObject var cDViewModel:CoreDataViewModel
    NavigationLink(destination: OtherChildView(cDViewModel: cDViewModel)){ }
}
// Other Child views...
```

### Second Tab View

```
struct ParentView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var cDViewModel:CoreDataViewModel
    NavigationLink(destination: ChildView2(cDViewModel: cDViewModel)){ }
}
struct ChildView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var cDViewModel:CoreDataViewModel
    NavigationLink(destination: OtherChildView(cDViewModel: cDViewModel)){ }
}
// Other Child views...
```

---

## Option 2

---

Please note that here I'm declaring the @StateObject in each of the parent views and not in the TabView section, for some reason I tend to like this option better but I'm not sure if this could create refreshing issues by having multiple @StateObject declarations.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var selectedView = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedView){
            ParentView1()
            .tabItem {
                Text("Parent View 1")
            }.tag(0)

            ParentView2()
            .tabItem {
                Text("Parent View 2")
            }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

### First Tab View

```
struct ParentView1: View {
    @StateObject var cDViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    NavigationLink(destination: ChildView1(cDViewModel: cDViewModel)){ }
}
struct ChildView1: View {
    @ObservedObject var cDViewModel:CoreDataViewModel
    NavigationLink(destination: OtherChildView(cDViewModel: cDViewModel)){ }
}
// Other Child views...
```

### Second Tab View

```
struct ParentView2: View {
    @StateObject var cDViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    NavigationLink(destination: ChildView2(cDViewModel: cDViewModel)){ }
}
struct ChildView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var cDViewModel:CoreDataViewModel
    NavigationLink(destination: OtherChildView(cDViewModel: cDViewModel)){ }
}
// Other Child views...
```

Comment: IMO in this scenario would be better to use StateObject in parent injected with .environmentObject() and EnvironmentObject in children where needed, to simplify interfaces and not overwhelming arguments.

Comment: Option 2 should be avoided: your view model should be used to share logic and properties among the views. Option 2 duplicates the properties, you lose the "source of truth". Best approach in my opinion was proposed by Asperi: inject the view model through `.environmentObject()`.

Comment: @Asperi - Ah, I see. So, in this case, the `@StateObject` would be injected in the `NavigationView` of the first view to appear on the screen, in my case, `ParentView1()`  and then it can be used in any other view, correct?.

Comment: This is not the correct way to do SwiftUI. You have to learn to use the structs and property wrappers, you'll find the managedObjectContext in the @Environment.

Comment: @malhal - Are you also suggesting injecting the `@StateObject` through the `.environmentObject()`? Or are you suggesting fetching objects directly from the views by injecting and accessing the manageObjectContext from the views? Would you mind eleaborating a little bit more.

Comment: No state objects, use @FetchRequest inside the View struct (FYI that is not the view in the MVC sense, it is a data struct)

Comment: But I'm trying to adapt to MVVM, not MVC. As far as I understand it, `@FetchRequest` and `@FetchedResults` don't work well with MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

I think this implementation is a slightly misguided attempt at achieving an `MVVM`-like architecture (trust me, I've been there).

In `MVVM` the so-called 'view model' is just as it sounds - a model for each view. It is the object that is responsible for keeping track of state for its view. If a user taps a button, the view model would be notified of the interaction, it does some internal recalculating of state, and then publishes that new state for the view to consume and implement. An example of this might be...

```
struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = MyViewViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Button("Hello") {
                viewModel.helloTapped()
            }
            if viewModel.helloIsVisible {
                Text("Why hello friend.")
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var helloIsVisible = false
    
    func helloTapped() {
        helloIsVisible = true
    }
}
```

In this example, the view model holds the state of the view (`helloIsVisible`) and publishes it for the view to consume. When the user interacts with the button, the view model recalculates state.

The flaws I see in your implementation are as follows:

- You seem to be combining the view model with what should be another object in the service layer of your app. Your view and view model should be completely dumb about how the data that drives your view (hopefully in the form of a concise model) were fetched from `CoreData`. You can delegate the task of fetching the data and packaging it into a consumable model for the view model into another object (another class) in the service layer of your app. This could be passed around the app in a number of ways, preferably as a dependency, but also perhaps instantiated as a public singleton. It would be wise to read up on the different techniques of making this service available. The view model would either ask this 'CoreData fetching' class for the data that it needs, or the data would be injected as a dependency. Read about singletons [here](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift) and dependency injection [here](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/02/02/microapps-architecture-in-swift-dependency-injection/).
- Each view should have its own view model. Presumably the views are different in some way - otherwise, why have more than one? Create a separate view model for each, that each uniquely manage the state of its corresponding view. They should each have a similar mechanism for retrieving data from the 'CoreData fetching' class.